# TikZ: Squiggly dashed arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to create a squiggly **and** dashed arrow in TikZ so that it does not look horrible? I think there is a way to modify the way the dashed pattern looks like. Has anyone ever encountered this problem and found the correct way to dash the arrow?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you post a Minimal Working Example of what you've tried, even if it looks horrible.

Comment: -also describe, what you mean by horrible. Maybe draw your expected/desired result.

Answer (score 4):

just guessing ...

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=snake]
\draw [decorate,dash pattern=on 0.5pt off 0.25pt, ->]
(0,0) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]